# php - what's the purpose of the operator [] when used empty

Tags: php

Can anyone please explain me what is the purpose of the `[]` operator in the following expression `[$field][]` here:

```
// Field rules
protected $_rules = array();

// Store the rule and params for this rule
$this->_rules[$field][] = array($rule, $params);
```

Comment: Creates a new integer index.

Comment: It append a new numeric-indexed element to the end of array

Comment: [Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will create a new (numbered) index for that array.

It's basically what [`array_push()`](http://www.php.net/array_push) does. (Except that `array_push` won't return a new Array-object)

Comment: `It's basically what array_push() does.` apart from the fact that `[]` will create a new array while `array_push()` wont